# Android : The vibrator does not stop vibrating

Tags: android, infinite, motorola, android-vibration

I have a strange issue with the vibrator object.

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(2 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
```

When the screen is on (even out of my app), it works just as expected.
But if I turn the screen off by pressing once the power button, the vibrator does not stop vibrating after the 2 seconds. It continues to vibrate indefinitely.

Note that this behavior only happens on my Motorola Moto E3. Do you have any idea how I can circumvent this?

Comment: Have you tried calling it on a separate thread, for example through an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Should it vibrate with you app in background? If not, you can try the method cancel() of Vibrator class on onPause & onDestroy

Comment: @ale.m Yes it should vibrate with my app in background, as I'm using it as a notification. I will try calling it on a separate thread. Let's wait and see.

Comment: @DanielKvist Calling it on a separate thread, makes it no longer vibrate at all. :(

Comment: @Denis Have you tried putting it in a method inside a `Service` ran at startup and then calling that method when you want it to vibrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything (postdelayed, services, new thread, ...), without any success. But I finally found a way to circumvent this bug on the Motorola Moto E3, using a pattern :

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(new long[]{0, 2 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS}, -1);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, the `Vibrator` works differently on different devices. The best idea is to `cancel()` the vibration in `onStop()` of your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

If what Roy proposed doesn't work. Try making a AlarmManager, and set it to go of in 2 seconds, and call vibrator.cancel() inside of it